# How should I remember the rules of logic?

Tags: logic

I'm taking a first course in discreet mathematics and there are  a lot of new rules/laws to remember.

My question is what is the best way to remember the rules of logic?
How would you remember the:

Absorption Laws

The Domination Laws

Identity Laws

Are there any well known mnemonics, like SOHCAHTOA in trigonometry?

Comment: Forget about mnemonics. From this point forward, you should be aiming for understanding, not memorization. If you *understand* what these laws are saying, you'll be able to remember them.

Comment: I do agree with Arturo's comment. But let me mention that for me Venn diagrams help a lot: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram 

You can think of the expression $p$ as selecting the collection $S(p)$ of things satisfying $p$. Then you have for instance $S(p \vee q) = S(p) \cup S(q)$ and $S(p \wedge q) = S(p) \cap S(q)$. The three laws you're mentioning are completely obvious once you draw the appropriate diagrams.

Comment: @Theo: Which, in a sense, is about understanding what the laws are saying. (-:

Comment: @Arturo: of course :)

Comment: Use them and you won't be able for forget them.

Comment: @Arturo you are so correct. I've practiced so many problems now that I can see at a glance how to apply the rules because I understand them now. No mnemonics needed.

Comment: @lampShade: Does your university offer courses in blabbermouth mathematics too? (-:  ("Discrete": made up of separate parts; "Discreet": capable of preserving prudent silence).

Answer (score 3):

[Arturo's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/how-should-i-remember-the-rules-of-logic#comment38928_17658) and [Raphael's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/how-should-i-remember-the-rules-of-logic#comment39004_17658) comments say it all:

> Forget about mnemonics. From this point forward, you should be aiming for understanding, not memorization. If you *understand* what these laws are saying, you'll be able to remember them.

To get to that point of understanding:

> Use them and you won't be able [to] forget them.